# Why int i = 2; printf("%d%d%d",i*=2,++i,i++) ouput 882

Tags: c

code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    printf("%d%d%d\n", i*=2, ++i, i++);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
882
```

Why the second number is 8

Comment: @tadman that was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The output is undefined behaviour. There's no answer to this question. Arguments can be evaluated in *any order* and using pre and post-increment operators in the same expression is asking for trouble.

In other words, that output is arbitrary because you can't depend on those behaviours.